# Exclude columns from Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

[image]

My current query

```
Select team, 
       stat_id, 
       max(statsval) as statsval 
from tbl 
group by team,
      statid
```

Issue :
I need to get season also in select and obliviously I need to add to group by but is is giving me un expected results I can't change my group by.Because I need to group by stat_id only I can group by season. I need to get the season of the max() record. Can some one help me on this?

I even tried

```
Select team, 
       stat_id, 
       max (seasonid),
       max(statsval) as statsval 
from tbl 
group by team,
         statid
```

But it takes the max season not exactly the correct result.

Excepted result

```
+--------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
| season |  team  | round | stat_id | statval |
+--------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
|   2004 | 500146 |     3 |       1 |       5 |
|   2007 | 500147 |     1 |       1 |       4 |
+--------+--------+-------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can't change your group-by-clause?

Comment: Because I need to group by stat_id only I can group by season. I need to get the season of the max() record.

Comment: what's the unexpected result you get if you add the group by? Probably you don't want the group by. Adding another column potentially splits a team, stat_id group if you have multiple seasons with same team and stat_id. Can you give an example of your expectation from the final query?

Comment: use a row_number to get the maxium and then filter by it

Comment: Can't you use a window function for this? which version your working on?

Comment: @Sami I am using sql server 12 and above. Can you give an example for that

Comment: @Arunbabu You need to edit your question add a sample data and expected results as _formatted text_ please not _images_.

Comment: @Sami, I changed the question description

Answer (score 0):

Try this and look up the team id after the grouping is done:

```
;with tmp as 
(
  select team, 
         stat_id, 
         max(statsval) as statsval 
  from tbl 
  group by team,
           statid
) 
select tmp.*, 
       tbl.seasonid 
from tmp join tbl 
on tmp.team = tbl.team and  tmp.statid = tbl.stat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your edition of SQL Server, this can be done with Window functions only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  team
    , stat_id
    , max(statsval) OVER (PARTITION BY team, stat_id) statsval
    , FIRST_VALUE(season_id) OVER (PARTITION BY team, stat_id ORDER BY  statsval DESC)
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using windows functions

```
Select distinct team, 
                statid, 
                max(statsval) OVER(PARTITION BY team,statid ORDER BY seasonid) as statid, 
                max(seasonid) OVER(PARTITION BY team,statid ORDER BY statid)
from tbl
```

Comment: The season will not match the result with the highest statsval.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the complete row, you can simply use a correlated subquery:

```
Select t.*
from tbl t
where t.season = (select max(t2.season) 
                  from tbl t2
                  where t2.team = t.team and t2.statsval = t.statsval
                 );
```

With an index on `tbl(team, statsval, season)`, this probably has as good as or better performance than other options.

A fun method that has worse performance (even with the index) is:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from tbl t
order by row_number() over (partition by team, statsval order by season desc);
```